# Grid built with Twitter Bootstrap and Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a simple modular grid built with Twitter Bootstrap (table) and Backbone.js that provides functionality like ajax loading, sorting, paginating and inline editing?

So far I found some solutions, but none to match this requirements:
- http://datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap_2/ -> Twitter Bootstrap & jQuery DataTables. I don't like this because all the grid logic (ui / model) is already implemented into one big, tightly-coupled file (jquery.dataTables.js)
- http://teleological.github.com/slickback/ -> SlickGrid (jQuery-backed datagrid) & Backbone. I also don't like this because first of all it uses a layer of abstraction to integrate with Backbone (slickback.js) and secondly the ui is mixed between Slickback and SlickGrid and cannot be easily adapted to Twitter Boostrap table for example.

Comment: Sadly none exists. You got knowledge try one of your own, that's how you learn CS `:)`

Answer (score 12):

Found it :) It's called Recline.js http://reclinejs.com

Comment: Just started building my own...I don't like cumbersome libraries with hundred/thousands of lines of code. I decided to use Twitter Bootstrap for the UI and ReclineJS (built on top of BackboneJS) for the model. If you're interested, check out this https://github.com/cosminnicula/ReclineTwitterBootstrapGridView

Comment: That's really interesting. I can't wait for a project so I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 7):

Try [bbGrid](https://github.com/direct-fuel-injection/bbGrid) on backbone and bootstrap.

Comment: Also check out [Backgrid.js](http://wyuenho.github.io/backgrid/)

Comment: @Pakman Do you know where I can find Backgrid.js's online demos?

Comment: @pathros [Is this what you're looking for?](http://backgridjs.com/#basic-example)?

Answer (score 3):

[Fuel UX](http://exacttarget.github.com/fuelux/#datagrid) provides a simple datagrid with bootstrap style. The datastore mechanism is very simple and you could implement it with backbone if you want.
I hope it helps you.